# Compute the irreducible components of an algebraic subset

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $V=V(I) \subset \mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{C}}^2$, with

$I=(x^3-y^3,x^2-y^2+2x-2y)$

I am looking to compute the irreducible components of the algebraic subset $V$. So far I have that $V(I)=V(x-y,x+y-2) \cup V(x-y,x^2+xy+y^2)$

but I am unsure of how to prove that these components are irreducible, or if this is even correct.
I know that in general

$V(I)$ irreducible $\iff I$ prime $\iff \mathbb{C}[x,y]/I$ an integral domain

but the quotient $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x-y,x+y-2)$ is a little more complicated than I'm used to and so I'm stuck, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Well, it seems $(x-y,x+y-2)=(x-1,y-1)$. Hope this helps.

Comment: That is helpful thank you! Applying similar logic to the other component I can then write $V(I)=V(x-1,y-1) \cup V(x,y)$